# How can a transaction have more than one recipient address?

Tags: transactions, address, receiving

I see a lot of transactions which have more than one recipient address.

Examples:

1. [Transaction 1](https://blockchain.info/tx-index/fce11cf87af6ee388c3a693dcc13a1e80b79e35029c347078d9ba4f07939ec83)
2. [Transaction 2](https://blockchain.info/tx-index/33175062ebe632822c195b811814bd43c0b12ca382a79f06ef692a03bd13bf7f)

Edit #1:
I just saw a tag call **multi-sig-transactions**. It is obviously what I am asking for.

I did not see in the clients before. How come that there are so many of them?

Edit #2:
After reading little bit about multi-sig-transactions I am not really sure that these transactions are these multi-sigs. This opinion is not based on real knowledge but just on such a great number of these transactions in every block.

Comment: Your title also applies to a transaction where you are simply paying two or more parties independently, but from  the same transaction.  You don't need Multi-sig for that, and Multi-sig is better described as a payment that can require more than one SENDER before it becomes valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, most transactions you see will have two recipient addresses. One is for the actual transaction and the other one is [change](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Change).

> When the output of a transaction is used as the input of another
>   transaction, it must be spent in its entirety. Sometimes the coin
>   value of the output is higher than what the user wishes to pay. In
>   this case, the client generates a new Bitcoin address, and sends the
>   difference back to this address. This is known as change.

But you can also add any number of recipients to a transaction so you'll find transactions with 20 or 50 receiving addresses too if you look around. In Bitcoin-Qt simply click "Add Recipient" on the "Send coins" tab.

Comment: Just to be sure: that means if I expect to receive 5 BTC on one specific address and a person sends 5 BTC to this address, I will see in the transaction's "out" part exactly 5 BTC with my specific address? And I can ignore all other addresses if they appear on the list?

Comment: Yes, that's right.